# No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1

Tags: asp.net, json, deserialization

my class is like this,

```
 public class SayfalarIletisim : IHarita
    {
        public string KordinatX{ get;  set; }

        public string KordinatY { get;set; }

        public string Adres{ get;set; }


        public string EkBilgi {get;set;}


      }
```

and presentation layer

```
var IletisimKaydet = function () {

    var adres=       App.txtIletisimAdres.getValue();
    var icerik=       App.txtIcerik.getValue();
    var kX=$('#lat').val();
    var kY=$('#lng').val();

    var dd = JSON.stringify({ 'Adres': adres, 'EkBilgi': icerik, 'KordinatX': kX, 'KordinatY': kY });


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'WebServiceAdmin.asmx/IletisimKaydet',
        data: "{'p':'" + dd + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (d) { Ext.Msg.notify('Uyarı', 'ekleme basarılı...'); },
        error: function () { Ext.Msg.notify('Uyarı', 'eklerken hata oluşdu!!!'); }
    });

};
```

I send data to web service like this , and parse it

```
 [WebMethod]
          public void IletisimKaydet(string p)
          {

              var serializer= new JavaScriptSerializer ();

            var jsonObjectSayfa = serializer.Deserialize<IList<SayfalarIletisim>>(p);

              dal_syf.GuncelleIletisim(jsonObjectSayfa[0]); 


          }
```

how ever I am getting this error when running those codes.

```
No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
```

what is wrong this code,before I run those kind of codes without no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use deserialization of class, not interface in your code.
Like that:

```
[WebMethod]
public void IletisimKaydet(string p)
{
     var serializer= new JavaScriptSerializer ();
     var jsonObjectSayfa = serializer.Deserialize<List<SayfalarIletisim>>(p);
     dal_syf.GuncelleIletisim(jsonObjectSayfa[0]); 
}
```

Concrete implementation `List<SayfalarIletisim>` supports interface `IList<SayfalarIletisim>`, so you still get the actual impl.

Comment: in that case,jsonObjectSayfa[0] return zero

Comment: When you create JSON you have to make sure that you send array. If you want to deserialize single entity use serializer.Deserialize<SayfalarIletisim>(p);